# PC to MCU ModBus Communication Problem

Tags: microcontroller, serial, communication, modbus

Im trying to create a communication between PC to MCU with ModBus, so i used pyserial at PC side and used freemodbus at MCU side. But it did not worked. I tested PC code with Modbus program and its ok, but MCU side failed. I checked the Tx/Rx pin of the MCU and got the result at the below. It seems responding with correct message but just after that there is some high to low transation (showed in the circle) at master side and communication failing. I couldnt find why that high to low transation happens.

Master = PC

Slave = MCU

Baudrate = 9600

Success of the communication sometimes almost perfect but sometimes there is no communication at all. I tried different baudrates could not figure at if there is any difference between results.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are any of these "bit-banged"/"software-defined" UART or do you have actual UART hardware? How are your transceivers connected? Do you have pull-up on the rx pin between the transceiver and the MCU?

Comment: @Lundin I have an actual UART hardware. Connection schematic added, there is no pull-up on the rx pin.

Comment: What happens if you add a pull-up then? I haven't used this part but apparently /RE is active low and DE is active high, so I'm not making any sense of your schematic. How exactly are you driving those 2 pins? What happens if you tie /RE to ground and DE to +5V?

Comment: @Lundin When common TE pin at reset state, Rx enabled / Tx disabled when it is at set state vice versa. Actually this  circuit used at multiple PCB for a 5+ years without problem.  I did not try that before, dont know what happens  when you try to activate Tx/Rx at the same time.

Comment: By the way how are you supposed to handle the intrabyte timing with 'modern' usb-serial bridges? if they decide to break the frame communication is toast… (modbus is framed by pauses)

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio If i understood you correctly. Interrupt and Timer are handling it pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

The *read holding register* response in Modbus RTU consists of:

- Slave address
- Function code (0x03 for read holding register command)
- Data bytes count (if you don't want to send nothing, then 0)
- Actual 16bit data (if any)
- CRC

A minimum of the packet would be 5 bytes with zero data. but the MCU response is 4 bytes (0x03 + 0 + 0x44B8).

If we consider the first 0x03 as a function code then it seems that your MCU doesn't send its own slave address.

Spontaneous, rare single transition shouldn't be a problem as the UART receivers ignore that.

Comment: Actually it just did not show the integrity of the message.  There is DeviceID, function code , byte count at the place you are seeing "0x03". I couldnt zoom it since i want you to see Tx/Rx messages and i checked if the message integrity is correct or not.

Comment: How does this explain the spike seen on the picture?